# Transferring values from void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, void, memcpy

Can someone tell me whats wrong with this code?

`base` is a void pointer to a bunch of `floats`
`i` is a value `>1`
`size` is the size of the type (in this case `float` - `4` )

```
char *a = (char *)base;
char *temp = (char *)a + size * (i/2);
printf("%d: %d = ", i, temp);
memcpy(a + size * i , temp , size);
printf("%d\n", a + size * i);
```

This is the output:

2: 136724 = 136728
3: 136724 = 136732
4: 136728 = 136736
6: 136732 = 136744
7: 136732 = 136748
8: 136736 = 136752

Comment: I do not believe that this code has that output.  If `a` is truly a `void*` then `a + size * i` is invalid because you cannot perform arithmetic on a void pointer.

Comment: What makes you think there's something wrong with it? What output were you expecting instead? Maybe you meant to *dereference* some of those pointers to print the values they're pointing at? You're just printing the addresses they store, which isn't very interesting.

Comment: Woops. Base is a void pointer and a is a char pointer. Code updated. How can I print the values?

Comment: @Kamran224: What "values" are you talking about?

Comment: `a[i]=a[i/2];` How can i make that happen using pointers? I come from a c++ / java background

Answer (score 1):

If `a` was a `void*`, the compiler wouldn't allow you to write `a + size*i` (you can't do pointer arithmetic with incomplete types).  Probably the type isn't what you think it is.

But why do you think there's a problem?  The left-hand column advances half as fast as the right-hand column, and this is expected because you are dividing by 2.

You do realize that you're printing addresses, and not the values being copied, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
char *a = (char *)base;
char *temp = (char *)a + size * (i/2);
printf("%d: %f = ", i, *(float *)temp);
memcpy(a + size * i , temp , size);
printf("%f\n", *(float *)(a + size * i));
```

The changes I have made are to dereference the pointers correctly (and casting them to the correct type) and to change %d to %f as you specified that base is an array of floats. %d is for ints and %f is for floats.

The reason your code did not work is that you were printing out the addresses and not the values.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please tell us what you're trying to accomplish? Seems like a
homework problem, right?

The C language allows you to cast any pointer to a void*, and then cast it
back to the original pointer type, without losing any information. Anything
else you do with a void pointer is a bad idea, although some library functions
(such as memcpy) still have void* for historical reasons. That's also why
you don't need an explicit cast to go from any pointer type to a void*.

You cannot look at what the void* points to, until you cast it back to the
correct pointer type. And be careful when you do!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

/* It's a bad idea to pass Base as a void pointer,
   but that's what you said you have. */
void silly_function(void*base, int i, int size) {
    /* Using a char* that points to float, is an even worse idea!
        char *a = (char *)base;
        char *temp = (char *)a + size * (i/2);
        printf("%d: %d = ", i, temp);
        memcpy(a + size * i , temp , size);
        printf("%d\n", a + size * i); 
    **/

    /** Probably ought to have a big SWITCH statement here, based
        on the data type. sizeof() isn't a good way to do this...
        On many computers, sizeof(float)==sizeof(long), but that
        doesn't mean that a float* is the same as a long* !!!
        For now, I'm going to assume (as you did) that base points
        to an array of float. */

    /* I think you're trying to copy the first half of the array
       into the second half of the array! But that's easy. */
    float*firsthalf = (float*)base; 
    float*secondhalf = firsthalf + (i/2);

    /* Show some starting values. */
    printf("Before: %x --> %f, %x --> %f\n",
        firsthalf, *firsthalf, secondhalf, *secondhalf);

    /* Now do the copy */
    memcpy(secondhalf, firsthalf, (i/2)*(sizeof(float)));

    /* Now prove that it's been copied? */
    printf("After:  %x --> %f, %x --> %f\n",
        firsthalf, *firsthalf, secondhalf, *secondhalf);
}

int main() {
    /* This drives the test */
    float ary[10] = {
        1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f, 5.5f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    silly_function(ary, 10, sizeof(ary[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, the output is

```
Before: 12ff38 --> 1.100000, 12ff4c --> 0.000000
After:  12ff38 --> 1.100000, 12ff4c --> 1.100000
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No such thing as memory.h in the C standard.